# Error starting Wildfly 8.2.1 server

Tags: java, server, wildfly

When I start the server by running the `standalone.bat` file I get the following error. I have searched google and found that maybe a port is used by NVidia and Wlidfly at the same time.

I would appreciate any help anybody can offer.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-14) MSC000
001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http:
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controlle
r.management.http: JBAS015811: Failed to start the http-interface service
        at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(Undertow
HttpManagementService.java:258) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(Se
rviceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceCont
rollerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already i
n use: bind
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.start(Management
HttpServer.java:156) [wildfly-domain-http-interface-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]

        at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(Undertow
HttpManagementService.java:224) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:
223) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) [rt.
jar:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67) [rt.
jar:1.8.0_45]
        at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.ja
va:182)
        at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:243)
 [xnio-api-3.3.0.Final.jar:3.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.start(Management
HttpServer.java:135) [wildfly-domain-http-interface-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
```

Comment: you have to stop the service which running on same(Wildfly)port then start the wildfly it will work.

Comment: try command 
 ps -ef | grep <service_name>
kill the service :
kill -9 process_id

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.....It was a port that NVidia was using. So i disabled the prossess 
Thnx